# blazor form complex model with list property - validation not working - FluentValidation?

Tags: c#, forms, model, blazor, fluentvalidation

I have a form for a person class and addresses list
and validation works only for 'main model class'
and it does not work for 'adress class' - why?

A simple example would look like this

```cs
<MudForm T="Person" Model="@person" Validation="@(personValidator.ValidateValue)" ValidationDelay="0">
    <MudTextField Label="Name" @bind-Value="person.Name" For="@(() => @person.Name)" />
    <MudTextField Label="Surname" @bind-Value="person.Surname" For="@(() => @person.Surname)" />
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Addresses:</label>
        <div class="address-list">
            @foreach (var address in person.Addresses)
            {
                <div class="address-item">
                    <MudTextField Label="Street" @bind-Value="address.Street" For="@(() => @address.Street)"  />
                    <MudTextField Label="City" @bind-Value="address.City" For="@(() => @address.City)"/>
                    <MudTextField Label="ZipCode" @bind-Value="address.ZipCode" For="@(() => @address.ZipCode)"/>
                    <MudButton Color="Color.Error" Variant="Variant.Text" OnClick="@(() => RemoveAddress(address))">Remove</MudButton>
                </div>
            }
            <MudButton Color="Color.Primary"  OnClick="@AddAddress">Add Address</MudButton>
        </div>
    </div>
    <MudButton Type="ButtonType.Submit" >Save</MudButton>
</MudForm>

@code {
    public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; } = "";
        public string Surname { get; set; } = "";
        public List<Address> Addresses { get; set; } = new();
    }

    public class Address
    {
        public string Street { get; set; }= "";
        public string City { get; set; } = "";
        public string ZipCode { get; set; } = "";
    }

    public class PersonValidator : AbstractValidator<Person>
    {
        public PersonValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(p => p.Name).NotNull().MinimumLength(4);
            RuleForEach(p => p.Addresses).Must(x => x.City.Length > 4).WithMessage("min4"); 
            RuleFor(p => p.Addresses)
                .Must(a => !a.Any(address => address.ZipCode.StartsWith("00-") && address.City == "Warszawa"))
                .WithMessage("Cannot have an address in Warsaw with a zipcode starting with '00-'");
        }

        public Func<object, string, Task<IEnumerable<string>>> ValidateValue => async (model, propertyName) =>
        {
            var result = await ValidateAsync(ValidationContext<Person>.CreateWithOptions((Person)model, x => { x.IncludeProperties(propertyName); }));
            if (result.IsValid)
                return Array.Empty<string>();
            return result.Errors.Select(e => e.ErrorMessage);
        };
    }
    private Person person = new Person();
    private PersonValidator personValidator = new PersonValidator();

    private void AddAddress()
    {    
        person.Addresses.Add(new Address());
    }

    private void RemoveAddress(Address address)
    {
        person.Addresses.Remove(address);
    }

    private async Task HandleValidSubmit()
    {
        // Do something when the form is submitted and valid
    }
}
```

so the quastion is
why this part not work? how to do it better? must be seperate form for subclasses in model ?

```
RuleForEach(p => p.Addresses).Must(x => x.City.Length > 4).WithMessage("min4"); 
RuleFor(p => p.Addresses)
                .Must(a => !a.Any(address => address.ZipCode.StartsWith("00-") && address.City == "Warszawa"))
                .WithMessage("Cannot have an address in Warsaw with a zipcode starting with '00-'");
```

Please advise

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 0):

You should define another validator for your address and then set it within your main validator like this.

```cs
public class AddressValidator : AbstractValidator<Address>
{
    public AddressValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.City)
            .MinimumLength(4);
    }
}


RuleForEach(p => p.Addresses).SetValidator(new AddressValidator());
```

Comment: hello thanks but this do not do not do validation also - did You checked this?  maybe this ValidateValue function must somehow call dis child validation also ?

Comment: You'll need to change your code to call `.Validate` instead of `.ValidateValue`

Comment: when i change to Validate(person) then there is no validation at all - maybe mudblazor forces that?